# With Maven, how can I build a distributable that has my project's jar and all of the dependent jars?

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a project  (of type 'jar') that (obviously) builds a jar.  But that project has many dependencies.  I'd like Maven to build a "package" or "assembly" that contains my jar, all the dependent jars, and some scripts (to launch the application, etc.)

What's the best way to go about this?  Specifically, what's the best way to get the dependents into the assembly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For a single module, I'd use an assembly looking like the following one (`src/assembly/bin.xml`):

```
<assembly>
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
    <format>tar.bz2</format>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/command</directory>
      <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.sh</include>
        <include>*.bat</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

To use this assembly, add the following configuration to your pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

In this sample, start/stop scripts located under `src/main/command` and are bundled into `bin`, dependencies are bundled into `lib`. Customize it to suit your needs.

Comment: I figured this was common enough to have warranted a built-in assembly..but apparently not.  Thanks, as always.

Comment: I really agree, it would make sense to have a predefined descriptor for something like this (based on some conventions, e.g. scripts location).

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution to create a distributable `.zip` (or `.tar.gz` / `.tar.bz2`) including all dependencies in a `lib` folder. It will:

1. Create a `jar` with a Manifest including the dependencies of the `lib` directory as the classpath and the main class to run when executing the `jar`.
2. Copy all dependent jars to the `target/lib` directory.
3. Create the distributable `zip with the main jar and all dependent jars of the lib directory.

Excerpt from `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- create distributable -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>full.path.to.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attached</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/resources/dist.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`dist.xml`:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>README*</include>
                <include>LICENSE*</include>
                <include>NOTICE*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/site</directory>
            <outputDirectory>docs</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The `dist.xml` was derived from the `bin` descriptor format here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#bin

Comment: Alternatively, you could add the `dependencySet` setting to the `dist.xml` as proposed by Pascal Thivent and get rid of the `maven-dependency-plugin` in the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the maven assembly plugin to packages everything in one single jar. you can find info here 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

HTH.