# Maven assembly include all jars but one (exclude doesn't work)

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to do exactly that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793017/789656

However, in my case I want some jars not being put in the lib folder. I tried to add

```
<excludes>
  <exclude>special*.jar</exclude>
</excludes>
```

But it doesn't do the trick, because as stated [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-assembly-plugin-LATEST/advanced-descriptor-topics.html)

> Include patterns take precedence over exclude patterns

How do I have to configure the assembly to achieve what I want?

Comment: Your question does not contain all the information needed. Post your pom.xml, assembly.xml, current output and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

HAve you tried adding an includes section:

```
        <includes>
            <include>**</include>
        </includes>
```

Before your excludes?

Answer (score 0):

Set that dependency's scope to provided. That should do the trick, if it's a direct dependency of your project. If it's not, then try to explicitly add it as a dependency of your assembly and still set it to scope:provided.