# How to get a zip of JARs to deploy in some server using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I like to deploy a maven project ("myproject"), that has some dependencies (e.g. spring, hibernate, ...), to some server, to be executed there.

I like to get a zip or tar like:

```
myproject-0.1.zip
|-- myproject.jar
|-- spring.jar
|-- hibernate.jar
|-- dependency3.jar
|-- dependencyN.jar
```

How can I do that with maven? I thought that must be a very usual task, but googling for it, gets me no usefull results ... (I do not want one single jar (as I can built with the maven-assembly-plugin))

Comment: Google still seems to work for me - [With Maven, how can I build a distributable that has my project's jar and all of the dependent jars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792763/with-maven-how-can-i-build-a-distributable-that-has-my-projects-jar-and-all-of)

Comment: @BoristheSpider Nice 1 :)

Comment: As far as I understand, this question isn't about building the zip of JARs but about deploying it to a server which serves as runtime container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the maven-assembly-plugin with the correct assembly-descriptor like this:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
          <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
          <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
          <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
          <unpack>false</unpack>
      </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

It will put all your file into a sub folder `lib` called which simply can be changed. Depending if you have multi-module project where you should have separate dist-module you need to change the value for `useProjectArtifact`.