# How do we generate a zip deployment package for AWS Lambda with all compiled class files and resource files at the root level using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, aws-lambda, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to create a deployment package for AWS Lambda with Java. We have been using maven-shade-plugin to generate an uber jar. However I saw that in the AWS Lambda's [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) under `Function Code` section, it is mentioned that

> Reduce the time it takes Lambda to unpack deployment packages authored in Java by putting your dependency .jar files in a separate /lib directory. This is faster than putting all your function’s code in a single jar with a large number of .class files.

So it seems to me that generating a zip deployment package could reduce cold start time. By following this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html), I could tell that the requirements for zip deployment are:

> All compiled class files and resource files at the root level.
>   All required jars to run the code in the /lib directory.

However, I am not able to generate such zip file with Maven. I tried configuring `maven-assembly-plugin` following steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793017/3213929)

The resulting zip file basically contains my jar on the root level, instead of the .class files as mentioned in the best practice.

Am I understanding this best practice suggestion incorrectly or could anyone tell me how to achieve this with maven?

Comment: Found the answer by following this link https://whirlysworld.blogspot.com/2016/03/aws-lambda-java-deployment-maven-build.html Hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The cited section does not say that you should upload `.class` files. It just says that you should separate the dependencies from your own jar. This is what the assembly plugin does.

Comment: edited my question by providing a link to the aws document where I saw this requirement being mentioned https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html